# I want to create this GUI Layout with java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

`enter code here`[image]

```
public class NWAHome {

 private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JLabel headerLabel;
   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JPanel controlPanel; 

   public NWAHome(){
      prepareGUI();
   } 

   public static void main(String[] args){
       NWAHome  swingMenuDemo = new NWAHome();     
      swingMenuDemo.showMenuDemo();
   }

   private void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Produkt anlegen");
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);

      headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
      statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);        

      statusLabel.setSize(350,100);
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            ColumnSpec.decode("128px"),
            ColumnSpec.decode("128px"),
            ColumnSpec.decode("128px"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            RowSpec.decode("113px"),
            RowSpec.decode("113px"),
            RowSpec.decode("113px"),}));

      mainFrame.getContentPane().add(headerLabel, "1, 1, fill, fill");
      mainFrame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, "3, 1, 1, 2, fill, fill");
      controlPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][]", "[][][][][]"));

      JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Projekt anzeigen");
      btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
      });
      controlPanel.add(btnNewButton_1, "flowy,cell 1 0");

      JButton button_1 = new JButton("Projekt anlegen");
      controlPanel.add(button_1, "cell 1 0");
      button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
      });

      JButton button = new JButton("Projekt ändern");
      controlPanel.add(button, "cell 1 1");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
      });

      JButton button_2 = new JButton("Projekt löschen");
      controlPanel.add(button_2, "flowy,cell 1 2");

      JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Projekt kopieren");
      controlPanel.add(btnNewButton, "cell 1 2");

      JButton button_3 = new JButton("Projekt archivieren");
      controlPanel.add(button_3, "cell 1 3");

      JButton button_4 = new JButton("Projekt importieren");
      controlPanel.add(button_4, "cell 1 4");
      mainFrame.getContentPane().add(statusLabel, "1, 2, fill, fill");
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private void showMenuDemo(){
      //create a menu bar
      final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

      //create menus
      JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Projekt");
      JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Produkt"); 
      final JMenu aboutMenu = new JMenu("Kriterien");
      final JMenu linkMenu = new JMenu("Bewertung");

      //create menu items
      JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Anlegen");
      newMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
      newMenuItem.setActionCommand("New");

      JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Anzeigen");
      openMenuItem.setActionCommand("Anzeigen");

      JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Ändern");
      saveMenuItem.setActionCommand("Ändern");
      JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Löschen");
      cutMenuItem.setActionCommand("Löschen");
      JMenuItem copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Kopieren");
      copyMenuItem.setActionCommand("Kopieren");
      JMenuItem archivierenMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Archivieren");
      archivierenMenuItem.setActionCommand("Archivieren");
      JMenuItem importierenMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Importieren");
      importierenMenuItem.setActionCommand("importieren");
      JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
      exitMenuItem.setActionCommand("Exit");







      MenuItemListener menuItemListener = new MenuItemListener();

      newMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      openMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      saveMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      exitMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      cutMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      copyMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
      importierenMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);

      final JCheckBoxMenuItem showWindowMenu = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show About", true);
      showWindowMenu.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(showWindowMenu.getState()){
               menuBar.add(aboutMenu);
            }else{
               menuBar.remove(aboutMenu);
            }
         }
      });

      final JRadioButtonMenuItem showLinksMenu = 
         new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Show Links", true);
      showLinksMenu.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(menuBar.getMenu(3)!= null){
               menuBar.remove(linkMenu);
               mainFrame.repaint();
            }else{                   
               menuBar.add(linkMenu);
               mainFrame.repaint();
            }
         }
      });

      //add menu items to menus
      fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
      fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
      fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.add(showWindowMenu);
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.add(showLinksMenu);       
      fileMenu.addSeparator();
      fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);        
      editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);
      editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);
      editMenu.add( importierenMenuItem);

      //add menu to menubar
      menuBar.add(fileMenu);
      menuBar.add(editMenu);
      menuBar.add(aboutMenu);       
      menuBar.add(linkMenu);

      //add menubar to the frame
      mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
   }
   class MenuItemListener implements ActionListener {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
             statusLabel.setText(e.getActionCommand() 
             + " JMenuItem clicked.");
          }    
       }
    }
```

Please can someone help me. I want to create this database GUI Layout so that when i click on enter button a new row appers but i don't kwow how to do it. I'm a new Java user and i'm trying to improve my Skills.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I will provide assistance rather than providing code  here what iam saying is a very basic one

1.first create a textfield and a button as

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
```

2.get entered text in textfield as `testField.getText()`

3.Assign this value to some variable say **data**

4.on button click insert retrieve data from text field as

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  String data = testField.getText();
  // .... do some operation on value ...
  }
  })
```

5.In action event use code to insert data into database using query

```
insert into createdtablename values('data');
```

here createdtablename is name of your created table

Hope my assistance guide you in right path how to do so.

Comment: Thanks i will try to do it

Comment: its just a simple code to insert data if you have got 2 or more values to be stored in your database use multiple textfields and follow code i show insert into createtablename values('value1','vlaue2','value3');